# modifiers and constraint apply , cancel the animation

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

recently I started to learn Blender and I have an issue with one of my animations,
I created a chain that should be rotated. when I use the animation everything works fine but when I click apply to the modifiers(curve and array) the animation does not work correctly:

here is how it works without applying:
[image]

here is how it works with applying:

[image]

I need to apply the animation for threejs, can you please help me how to handle it, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you do not show how you've setup the relation between the object and the curve so that it moves the chain in the first place. So I can only guess: the array modifier places the elements on the curve and moving the curve or the object results in moving the segments. When you apply the modifier, this generates a fixed mesh in the state it's in that moment or on that frame. Afterwards there is no dynamic relation to the location of the curve anymore because you have fixated the segments by applying the modifier.

Comment: As it is now, you have no animation for the rotation of the chain. The only thing animated is the movement in X direction. The rotation is just a reaction of the changing locations between curve and chain object. Without the modifier, this reaction doesn't occur.

Comment: you guessed correctly Im creating an array modifier and placing the elements on the curve and moved the object. maybe this is not the correct way to create the animation, can you please give me guidelines on how to do that, maybe with Amature?